# MsDeploy using dbDacFx resets the sequence values

Tags: database, sequence, msdeploy, dacpac

I'm trying to deploy a database by updating the schema with a dacpac file. I'm using the dbDacFx function in MsDeploy. Everything seems to be working fine except that the target database's sequences gets reset to the default values declared in the database project, which I don't want happening. I don't see any DacDepl oyOptions to ignore sequence values.

Is there a way to exclude the reset of sequence values during this process.